# linux for AMD Sempron 2800+ on 1GB RAM

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, lubuntu, amd, bodhi

My first try of Linux is on old AMD Sempron 2800+ (with 1 GB RAM) that works on WinXP, but I want to install Linux. . I've tried (32-bit) Lubuntu, Linux Lite, Bodhi, LXLE. (lubuntu-17.10.1-desktop-i386, linux-lite-3.8-32bit, bodhi-4.5.0-legacy, lxle_16.04.3_32)

Each time I'm making live USB and I have set BIOS to boot from usb first.
The initialization starts, and when I choose install, on each of tried distros comp freezes and I can only reset it.

When I tried starting Linux Lite 3.8 in safe mode, after some unpacking (and really long idle time) the computer turned off. The same happened when I tried running it from DVD - comp turned off after selecting "Start Linux Lite".

Computer works under Win XP.

Comment: Does FreeBSD boot?

Comment: I'll look into it.

Comment: Given the symptoms you describe, I'd try looking for a hardware problem.  Run Memtest86+ to check the RAM, Prime95 to check the CPU, and if you've got WinXP running, a suitably old graphics benchmark to test the graphics card.

Comment: Thank you Mark, it turned out to be graphic card that was making problems...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was definitely hardware-based: the graphic card was malfunctioning, which somehow made more problems on Linux than it had on Win XP.

With different graphic card I was able to install (in fact to run Live Linux from USB) various instances: Light Linux, LXLE, Bodhi and Lubuntu. They all worked, and those were latest versions, as listed in the first post.

For this hardware, as YouTube stream goes, the best was working Lubuntu in safe mode.